# Как сделать синхронный вертикальный скролл двух элементов?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Всем привет! Имеется вот такой макет (скрин прилагается), как видно из изображения, слева есть текстовая область, а справа есть закрепленный фон телевизора, внутри которого уже динамический контент. Идея состоит в том, что при скролле, одновременно должна скроллиться текстовая область слева и соответствующая картинка (внутри телика) справа. Пока совсем не вдупляю как это сделать. Поделитесь, пожалуйста, идеями, мыслями, желательно кодом.
P.S. контентная область прибита к правому краю, слева же чутка margin. Элементы должны скроллиться вверх-вниз. Справа, очевидно, будут картинки и предполагается, что они появляются с fade эффектом.

[image: макет]

Comment: Высота текста слева и высота контента в телевизоре одинаковые?

Comment: Текст разного объема, но родительский блок с текстом и контентом в телевизоре равны.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const leftEl = document.querySelector('.left');
const leftWr = leftEl.querySelector('.text-wrapper');
const rightEl = document.querySelector('.right');
const rightWr = rightEl.querySelector('.text-wrapper');


leftEl.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  //соотношение прокруток будет равно соотношению высот внутренних элементов
  //за вычетом высоты родителя
  //отсюда получаем формулу расчета прокрутки правого блока в зависимости от левого
  rightEl.scrollTop = leftEl.scrollTop * (rightWr.clientHeight - rightEl.clientHeight) / (leftWr.clientHeight - leftEl.clientHeight);
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #e4e4e4;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left text">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      first<br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> last
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right text">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      first<br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> text
      <br> last
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Где то такой вопрос был уже так как я уже отвечал на него

```js
syncScroll($('.item1'), $('.item2'));

function syncScroll(el1, el2) {
  var $el1 = $(el1);
  var $el2 = $(el2);
  var forcedScroll = false;

  $el1.scroll(function() {
    performScroll($el1, $el2);
  });
  $el2.scroll(function() {
    performScroll($el2, $el1);
  });

  function performScroll($scrolled, $toScroll) {
    if (forcedScroll) return (forcedScroll = false);
    var percent = ($scrolled.scrollTop() /
      ($scrolled[0].scrollHeight - $scrolled.outerHeight())) * 100;
    setScrollTopFromPercent($toScroll, percent);
  }


  function setScrollTopFromPercent($el, percent) {
    var scrollTopPos = (percent / 100) *
      ($el[0].scrollHeight - $el.outerHeight());
    forcedScroll = true;
    $el.scrollTop(scrollTopPos);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.items,
.items:after,
.items:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

i.fa {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

span.title {
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  ;
}

.item1 {
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  float: left;
  padding: 150px 0;
}

.item1 p {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.item2 {
  width: calc(100% - 350px);
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  float: right;
}

.item-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item-div div {
  width: 45vw;
  height: 30vw;
}

.item2 i.fa {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

.item2 h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.item2 span {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.item1,
.item2 {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.item1::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

.item2::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="items">
  <div class="item1">
    <div class="customScroll1">
      <p>
        <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
        <span class="title">Heading title one</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>
        <span class="title">Heading title two</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <i class="fa fa-television"></i>
        <span class="title">Heading title tree</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
        <span class="title">Heading title four</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
        <span class="title">Headeing title fife</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
        <span class="title">Headeing title six</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="item2">
    <div class="customScroll2">


      <div class="item-div">
        <!--item-div-->
        <div>
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
          </p>
          <h3>Heading title one</h3>
          <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium quis repellat nesciunt, ex temporibus perspiciatis esse perferendis. Dicta tempore dolore laborum iste rerum quis temporibus voluptate itaque maxime commodi! Maiores.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--item-div-->

      <div class="item-div">
        <!--item-div-->
        <div>
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>
          </p>
          <h3>Heading title two</h3>
          <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium quis repellat nesciunt, ex temporibus perspiciatis esse perferendis. Dicta tempore dolore laborum iste rerum quis temporibus voluptate itaque maxime commodi! Maiores.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--item-div-->

      <div class="item-div">
        <!--item-div-->
        <div>
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-television"></i>
          </p>
          <h3>Heading title tree</h3>
          <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium quis repellat nesciunt, ex temporibus perspiciatis esse perferendis. Dicta tempore dolore laborum iste rerum quis temporibus voluptate itaque maxime commodi! Maiores.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--item-div-->

      <div class="item-div">
        <!--item-div-->
        <div>
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
          </p>
          <h3>Heading title four</h3>
          <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium quis repellat nesciunt, ex temporibus perspiciatis esse perferendis. Dicta tempore dolore laborum iste rerum quis temporibus voluptate itaque maxime commodi! Maiores.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--item-div-->

      <div class="item-div">
        <!--item-div-->
        <div>
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
          </p>
          <h3>Heading title fife</h3>
          <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium quis repellat nesciunt, ex temporibus perspiciatis esse perferendis. Dicta tempore dolore laborum iste rerum quis temporibus voluptate itaque maxime commodi! Maiores.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--item-div-->

      <div class="item-div">
        <!--item-div-->
        <div>
          <p>
            <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
          </p>
          <h3>Heading title six</h3>
          <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium quis repellat nesciunt, ex temporibus perspiciatis esse perferendis. Dicta tempore dolore laborum iste rerum quis temporibus voluptate itaque maxime commodi! Maiores.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--item-div-->


    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```